# Is a Gdk::ModifierType computer dependent?

Tags: events, gtk3, keyevent, gtkmm3

I can capture Gdk::ModifierType. When I do mouse button events the modifier emits
**272** for a left click
**1040** for a right click
**16** for a button release
If I run my program on another computer will it emit the same signals for mouse events?

Comment: It should. Post an MCVE so we can test it and report back :)

Comment: What is an MCVE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve